# Usar tipos que aceptan valores Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Necesito totalizar las columnas en un `GridView` pero suecede que existen algunos datos nulos y me lanza una excepcion:

> {No se puede convertir DBNull.Value al tipo System.Decimal. Utilice un tipo que acepte valores NULL.}

Mi código es:

```
decimal totalCapital = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .Sum(row => row.Field<decimal>("Capital"));

GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = totalCapital.ToString("N2");
```

Estuve investigando pero no sé cómo adaptar `Nullable` a mi código.

Comment: Prueba `decimal? totalCapital = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal?>("Capital"));`. De todas maneras, si estas usando `Sum`,  lo que debes hacer es filtrar los campos que sean null ya que no van a influir en la suma:`decimal totalCapital = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x["Capital"]!=DBNull.Value).Sum(row => row.Field<decimal>("Capital"));`

Comment: me marca rojo el toString de aqui: totalCapital.ToString("N2");

Comment: Si, no es una buena idea. Mira mi comentario editado, filtra con `Where` los que sean nulos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendrías que filtrarlo usando

```
decimal totalCapital = dt.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(row=> row["Capital"] != DBNull.Value)
                         .Sum(row => row.Field<decimal>("Capital"));
```

de esta forma ya no tendrías problemas con la conversión al tener un `null` en esa celda.

También podrías hacerlo sin filtrar usando

```
decimal totalCapital = dt.AsEnumerable()
                         .Sum(row => row["Capital"] == DBNull.Value ? (decimal)0 : row.Field<decimal>("Capital"));
```

si detecto un `null` el resultado será cero

Comment: @Pikoh perfecto, gracias

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, he intentado de las dos formas pero en las dos me lanza el error: {"La conversión especificada no es válida."} System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

Comment: mm, podria ser en la segunda forma porque intenta castear el cero a int y es diferente del decial, lo veo dificil de la primer forma ya que filtras y luego aplicas la conversion, sino esta claro que el campo que intentas convertir a decimal no lo es realmente

Comment: tenia razon usted no era decimal era int, Gracias ya funciono